# Some part if my SQL Server stored procedures are not executing after adding ssl, it does before

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a commerce portal in ASP.NET MVC and SQL Server as the backend. The site itself dynamic all content including the main menu is generated at runtime. After completing the work I hoisted it (they had 2 servers 1 for the front end and 2nd one for SQL Server), and it worked fine.

The problem started when they added a SSL certificate, they said it was to improve speed but some part of my procedures (like loops, tables containing huge data) are returning no result instead it returns NULL.

There is no connection issue. For example there is a query to get the main header part of the page, the procedure itself is running except this section

```
DECLARE @UDO_DEFAULT_VENDORLOCATION NVARCHAR(150) = 
        (SELECT TOP 1 TAB1.vendorcode + N'|' + CAST(othervendorlocation AS VARCHAR(30)) + N'|' + '-D' + N'|' + TAB2.locationX + N'|' + TAB2.locationY + N'|' + TAB2.areacode + N'|' + TAB3.name + N'|' + TAB3.pincode + N'|' + TAB3.countrycode + N'|' + TAB3.countryname + N'|' + TAB3.statecode + N'|' + TAB3.statename + N'|' 
         FROM ec_company TAB1
         INNER JOIN ec_vendors_locations TAB2 ON TAB1.othervendorlocation = TAB2.vendorlocationcode 
                                              AND TAB1.vendorcode = TAB2.vendorcode 
         INNER JOIN udv_lang_area TAB3 ON TAB3.areacode = TAB2.areacode 
                                       AND TAB3.lancode = @UDO_PARAM_LANGUAGE )
```

I'm using `|` to split the content later. This query will run fine when the ssl is removed.

I even created a domain with no ssl and called this from that domain and it worked fine. This part never will work with ssl rest of the procedure is working great. Some other procedures are also having this issue.

I've no idea what causing this issue ? They are using the amazon servers. Does someone know why this is happening ??!!

Is this has anything to do with my `web.config`? There is connection and procedure are running except some sections that makes me confused! Please help me

Comment: T-SQL does not "partially" run stored procedures, SSL has nothing to do with stored procedure execution, and adding SSL certificates has nothing to do with improving speed. More than likely, different code is executing, or you're connected to a different database, or a proxy is caching results, depending on what backend your connections happen to go to. Start from the ground up and trust nothing. Verify that there's no cache, that you're looking at the right server, that the stored procedure looks what it should look like on that server, that the DB tables are actually filled, etc.

Comment: its running but returns null, it will bring result on a non ssl domain the same sql server!! i just changed the domain thats it. I added comments as a result in my stored procedure and it called in both cases. Both domains executed it and when it got this part it returned null and in non ssl domain it returned the result, i used the same db server for both domains!

Comment: There are a few ways textually identical queries on the same server can return different results: different parameter values, different `SET` options in effect, a view that incorporates aspects of the login or connection to return different data, row-level security, or different user accounts with different schemas (in order of decreasing probability). Encryption on the connection is not a factor, though, because that only comes into play for transmitting the data. Try things like `SELECT @@OPTIONS, SUSER_SNAME()` to verify settings.

Comment: The use of "select top 1" implies that you expect multiple rows to be returned by your select statement. The absence of an order by clause means that you don't care which row is used. That is often a logical mistake - which implies that your code likely has other assumptions built into it. These assumptions can often be exposed in situations where the server load is much more severe - which is more likely in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

This is a troubleshooting suggestion not an answer, but it isn't readable in a comment.

I think Jeroen is on the right track with this one, maybe the security context is changing when you run it on the server with SSL, possibly because a setting is different, or possibly because with SSL enabled a different authentication method is being used. The easiest way to see if a different security context is being used is to embed CURRENT_USER() in the specific query having problems. Don't do it in SSMS, do it in the query, so your above code becomes

(NOTE: You may have to increase the size of @UDO_DEFAULT_VENDORLOCATION to hold the additional characters!)

```
DECLARE @UDO_DEFAULT_VENDORLOCATION NVARCHAR(150) = 
     (SELECT TOP 1 TAB1.vendorcode + N'|' 
       + CAST(othervendorlocation AS VARCHAR(30)) + N'|' + '-D' + N'|' 
       + TAB2.locationX + N'|' + TAB2.locationY + N'|' + TAB2.areacode + N'|' 
       + TAB3.name + N'|' + TAB3.pincode + N'|' + TAB3.countrycode + N'|' 
       + TAB3.countryname + N'|' + TAB3.statecode + N'|' + TAB3.statename + N'|' 
       + N'#' + CURRENT_USER() --ADD this line!
   FROM ec_company TAB1
         INNER JOIN ec_vendors_locations TAB2 
           ON TAB1.othervendorlocation = TAB2.vendorlocationcode 
                  AND TAB1.vendorcode = TAB2.vendorcode 
         INNER JOIN udv_lang_area TAB3 ON TAB3.areacode = TAB2.areacode 
                  AND TAB3.lancode = @UDO_PARAM_LANGUAGE )
```

and run it both with and without SSL. *Post both results back here.*

Again, it's vital that you do this in the query, not just in a SSMS window because you need to see what security context is ACTUALLY being used, just running it in SSMS can give you a different answer.

If the context is the same, try Jeroen's other suggestion, repeat this test with @@OPTIONS to see if they are the cause. Decoding the results of @@OPTIONS can be a bit more work, though (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/options-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) so I'd just check the security context first. And @@OPTIONS doesn't capture everything, either, you may still need to explore server settings, but those should be the same in SSMS and therefore easier to view (but there are many).